# Compute PCA with ITK in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, pca, itk

I am working with some DICOM images and I use ITK for this. I would like to compute the PCA of a binary image of a tumor. I found and tried to use the [ImagePCADecompositionCalculator](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImagePCADecompositionCalculator.html) class, but could not retrieve the mean, eigenvalues or eigenvectors. It seems only to be used to create some statistical shape model with multiple images.

```
void PCA(DICOMImage image) {

    using FilterType = itk::ImagePCADecompositionCalculator<ImageType>;

    FilterType::Pointer filter = FilterType::New();
    filter->SetImage(image.getImage());
    filter->Compute();

    qDebug() << filter->GetReferenceCount();
    // how to retrieve mean, eigenvalues and eigenvectors?
}
```

I also tried to use openCV for this, but the results are very strange.

```
typedef itk::Point<double, 3> PointType;    
PCA computePCA(vector<PointType> coords) {

    qDebug() << "computing PCA with" << coords.size() << "elements";
    Mat data = Mat(int (coords.size()), 3, CV_32F);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < coords.size(); ++i) {
        data.at<double>(int (i), 0) = coords.at(i)[0];
        data.at<double>(int (i), 1) = coords.at(i)[1];
        data.at<double>(int (i), 2) = coords.at(i)[2];
    }
    
    PCA pca(data, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, 3);
    
    std::cout << pca.mean << std::endl;
    std::cout << pca.eigenvalues << std::endl;
    std::cout << pca.eigenvectors << std::endl;
 
    return pca;
}
```

Gives me the following results:

```
computing PCA with 162337 elements
[nan, 3.3579757, nan]
[nan;
 nan;
 nan]
[nan, nan, nan;
 nan, nan, nan;
 0, 0, 1]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use the correct mat type CV_64FC1: `Mat data = Mat(int (coords.size()), 3, CV_64FC1);`

Comment: Thanks, I know have values that make much more sense. I didn't use openCV a lot: why has it to be `CV_64FC1`? From what I understand, CV stands for openCV, 64 for 64 bits, F for floating point, but no idea about C1.

Comment: C1 = 1 channel. Since you are accessing the mat with .at<double> you need 64FC1. If you the type is 32FC1 then you need .at<float>

Answer (score 0):

To compute principal component of variation, you need to have some variation. What does vary in your case?

From a single image of a tumor, you can compute principal axes and some other statistics available via [ShapeLabelObject](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ShapeLabelObject.html).

See this [Example](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Filtering/LabelMap/LabelBinaryRegionsAndGetProperties/Documentation.html) and [filter docs](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1BinaryImageToShapeLabelMapFilter.html).

Comment: I use the coordinates of the tumor as variables. This way I can get an axis corresponding to the biggest axis of an ellipsoid approximation.

Comment: Then you want the first vector in `GetPrincipalAxes()` from `ShapeLabelObject` class.